# Why do people comment unrelated to the question?

Tags: discussion

I've used Stack Overflow for a good three days now... I've had two posts and 90% of the comments/answers are extremely unhelpful and unrelated to my question. One generous contributor answered my question (I spent days trying to find an answer). But due to people commenting on completely unrelated things, my question was downvoted, and I believe a lot of people could find it useful.

People on this site specify on asking good questions... Why don't they focus on editing/commenting/answering productively?

If this site is meant for experienced programmers, and not noobs trying to learn like myself, then that should be mentioned somewhere.

Comment: _"If this site is meant for experienced programmers, and not noobs trying to learn like myself, then that should be mentioned somewhere."_ From the first line of the [Tour,](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) linked to you when you first sign up and also found in the "Help" menu of the top bar: _"Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers."_ So, yes, it is mentioned somewhere. It's also mentioned in the help center.

Comment: That said, "noobs" _can_ ask questions here as well. My first question was a beginner question, as I was brand new to programming. I suggest you read the [ask] page in the help center and see if anything there helps you figure out why the "unrelated" comments were posted. It could be they _were_ relevant and you just don't know how they were relevant yet. (They could be completely unrelated, but you should assume they are at first and try to figure out why.)

Comment: @Kendra My point is there should be a "How to answer" page

Comment: There is: [answer] also in the help center.

Comment: I see no any unrelated to question comments there.

Comment: @Kendra A how to answer page that people follow as strict as the how to ask page

Comment: One reason you are posting questions to ask for free help from skilled and experienced professionals.  If you want precise control over what developers say and do, pay them.

Comment: After checking out your only undeleted question, I only see one comment _potentially_ unrelated. So I assume the comments you're talking about are on your deleted question? It would help to link to the question you want clarification of the comments on, as otherwise this is all going to be speculation.

Comment: @Qwertiy I want to be clear that I don't mean this in general. Only in restricted circumstances, especially with newcomers

Comment: _"A how to answer page that people follow as strict as the how to ask page"_ As far as I've seen, for as long as I've been here, people follow "how to answer" better than "how to ask." We have a _ton_ of horrible, poorly asked, off-topic questions asked _every day._ But the answers I get, or the answers I find to my searches for problems, tend to follow "how to answer" decently well.

Comment: @MartinJames I understand your point, but I want to be in the position to help people in the future... That's the point of a giving community.  It is more related to the 'how to answer' (which i haven't read yet so I don't know if it allows unrelated comments) being as strict as the 'how to ask'

Comment: SO has not really been a 'giving community' for some time.  It's now a 'take all you can get' cult:(

Comment: @Salt but you yourself want it "for the future." i see a lot more value in telling visitors to the site "don't try this behavior"if it's a bad one. Doesn't matter if YOU want it, it should be exposed as a bad idea.

Comment: @Salt Please do not deface your question.

Answer (score 10):

> But due to people commenting on completely unrelated things, my
>   question was down voted

I think your post was downvoted because it needed some improvement. If you think that a comment is not useful, then mark it as *not constructive* and move on. Usually comment flags are handled faster than flags on questions / answers.

> Why don't they focus on editing/commenting/answering productively?

Honestly, why do you even worry about **other people** not focusing on something?. If there is something to be learnt, take it, if it is useless, *flag it*.  FYI- there are people in some chatrooms *editing/commenting* on posts to improve the overall quality of posts on SO. (We do have a lot of people on SO editing / reviewing / commenting on posts to ensure that the quality doesn't go down :P)

> If this site is meant for experienced programmers, and not noobs
>   trying to learn like myself, then that should be mentioned somewhere.

SO is meant for everyone and not just experts. All we want are **good posts**, honestly we don't care who posts them. We see lots of questions from newbies. **Posts are almost always closed / DVed based on its quality and not based on the person who posted them**. If you see a lot of DVs, comments, then you should perhaps stop for a moment and consider the comments on your posts and try to improve your post.

Comment: OP: _"I've used SO for a good three days now"_ - You: _"If you think that a comment is not useful, then mark it as not constructive"_ - I don't think you should be giving that advice, because OP is both a beginning programmer and a beginning SO user, so they will not know very well what a useful comment looks like. Unless you don't already have enough flags in the queue that you wish to dismiss.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Sooner or later, the OP will have to know how to use flags :). I agree with you that it might take some time for him / her to understand how SO works. Anyways, that part of the answer (in general) meant - *we have processes in place to handle useless comments*

Comment: @TheLostMind But there's no indication of improper comments here, merely the OP misunderstanding how the system works, so telling him to flag the comments of people trying to help him improve his question because they dared to do something other than give him teh codez is just going to cause problems.  He needs to understand that the appropriate response to a bad question isn't to post an answer, and telling him to flag comments of people trying to improve the question won't help him get there.

Comment: @Servy - Again, what I was trying to say is that **one can always flag comments on posts if they are useless**. Now, we should not assume that the OP will flag a lot of comments as "not constructive" just because he is "new". Added *f you see a lot of DVs, comments, then you should perhaps stop for a moment and consider the comments on your posts and try to improve your post.* to my answer just to make it clearer.

Comment: @TheLostMind When the OP asks what to do when people post constructive comments trying to help him improve his question instead of answering an unanswerable question, and your response is, "you should flag comments you think aren't useful" then yes, you **would** expect him to start flagging comments that aren't inappropriate, because that's what you're telling him to do.  I wouldn't expect him to flag appropriate comments *if a mod wasn't telling him to do just that*.